# "toggle" between 2 values in array - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

If I have an array containing an order of variables, lets use 2 colors for example:

```
["red","blue","red","blue","red","red"]
```

Is there a built-in function or well known method to "invert" the colors to the other color, so you end up with the result:

```
["blue","red","blue","red","blue","blue"]
```

---

**SOME CONTEXT**

So I have 3 arrays, one of colors like the above example, one with html ID's which looks like `["blue01","red01","blue02","blue03",...]` and another with cell references in them looking like `["B2","D2","B3","B4",...]`. I want to be able to "toggle" these variables in each array, as explained in the example above.

**CURRENT CODE**

At the minute I just have an event handler that hard codes the changes as such:

```
  $("#myonoffswitch").on("change",function(d){
    team = (team =="blue")? "red" : "blue" ;
    if (team =="blue"){
      divRange = ["blueBan1","redBan1","bluePick1","redPick1","redPick2","bluePick2","bluePick3","redBan2","blueBan2","redPick3","redPick4","bluePick4","bluePick5","redPick5"];
      cellRange = ["B12","D12","B2","D2","D3","B3","B4","D13","B13","D4","D5","B5","B6","D6"];
    }
    else{
      divRange = ["redBan1","blueBan1","redPick1","bluePick1","bluePick2","redPick2","redPick3","blueBan2","redBan2","bluePick3","bluePick4","redPick4","redPick5","bluePick5"]
      cellRange = ["D12","B12","D2","B2","B3","D3","D4","B13","D13","B4","B5","D5","D6","B6"];
    };
  });
```

Comment: Loop through the array(s) and change the values.

Comment: i think the method i have in place is simpler than looping through, the divRange variables would be annoying to "toggle" with a for loop.
- Agreed that would be another way of achieving this though.

Comment: What is your question then? "clean" is not an objective criteria, and if you're looking for opinions, SO doesn't do those. You *might* be able to ask this question on [codereview.se], but you should read their help center to determine if it is on topic.

Comment: I'll amend the question then, i guess what i'm asking is, is there a built in function? i was hoping to see if anyone knew neat ways of doing it by some other method if a built in method is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var array = ["red","blue","red","red","blue","red","blue"];

array = array.map( colour => colour === "red" ? "blue" : "red");

console.log(array);
```

If you have IDs after the colours, as you requested :

```js
var array2 = ["red05","blue123","red85","red741","blue456","red789","blue320"];

array2 = array2.map( colour => colour.indexOf("red") > -1 ? colour.replace("red","blue") : colour.replace("blue","red"));

console.log(array2);
```

Comment: this is nifty, i think i prefer defining the mapping like this although @Redu answer works too. Would you know of a way to do this on the Array of IDs that have numbers after them, would it be something like `colour === "red*" ? "blue*" : "red*" ?

Answer (score 2):

I might do the job like this. Though i can not make sure if there is a better way of doing this

```js
var arr = ["red","blue","red","blue","red","red"],
    map = {red :0, blue:1, lut: ["blue","red"]};
    arr = arr.map(e => map.lut[map[e]]);
console.log(arr);
```